# How to select all picklist value on making checkbox true

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist

I have dynamic picklist value on visualforce page and I have requirement where when I make check box true then all picklist values should get selected.

Please help me on this

Comment: Create an action function which call a method on your controller to set the picklist values. Call this action function onChange of your checkbox.

Comment: If you could put the code that you tried, then we can discuss on what to do next or what is not working.